# Select distinct combinations of rows

Tags: postgresql

I try to select distinct combinations of rows (`author_id`, `recipient_id`), preserving following `order` and `limit`. Like on Facebook you have a list of recent conversations with given users. For example I'm a user with id=665 and I need a list of 20 recent conversations, 20 last distinct people a user with id=665 has talked. My current code:

```
select * from (
  select distinct on (author_id, recipient_id) * from private_message where author_id=665 or recipient_id=665
) p_m
order by id desc
limit 20;
```

[image]

In this case everything is ok besides that I want to keep **bigger** `id` (more recent), so message with id=10 needs to be drop, because it's duplicate of id=18.

So the expected result is:

[image]

Comment: Why did you include `or recipient_id=665` remove that and you get desired output

Comment: If query only includes `author_id=665` it will not work out. Let's say you didn't write to anybody within a month, then you would geta list of very old conversations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right you would like the last row for each column combination (regardless of column order). Easiest is probably to enumerate the rows (using least, GREATEST for column order) in desc order and choose the first one

```
SELECT ... FROM (
    SELECT...
           , row_number() over (partition by least(author_id, recipient_id)
                                           , greatest(author_id, recipient_id) 
                                order by updated_at desc) as rn
    FROM private_message
    WHERE 665 IN (author_id, recipient_id) 
) as t
WHERE rn = 1
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my problem, but I'm afraid it doesn't solve my problem. I've already edited my question.

Comment: @TomaszSuperson: just change `where rn = 1` to `where rn <= 20`

Comment: Sorry if you get me wrong, but what I want to get is a list of 20 last conversations , 20 last people a user with `id=665` has talked (not one row for each column combination). That means I need exactly 20 rows where recipient_id=665 or author_id=665. There shouldn't be rows where for example `recipient_id=665, author_id=1` and `recipient_id=1, author_id=665` , because on a website on the list of last conversations there will be duplicate with `id=1`.

Comment: *  20 last **distinct** people a user with id=665 has talked